# Python Detect anything dropped in a directory

Tags: python

We have one requirement in our project that detect anything that is dropped into a directory in python.

The process is like this:

- There will be a python script running almost all time a day(sort of cron job), which will keep watch on a directory.
- When anybody puts a file into a directory that file should be detected.
- File dropped will have zip, xml, json or an ini format.
- There is no fix way that how user will drop the file into that directory (i.e person could simply copy or move it using `console` by `cp or mv` command. Or person might do a `FTP transfer` from some other computer, or  may upload it through our `web interface`)

I'm able to detect it while dropped by web interface but not for other ways.

Can anyone suggest me the way to detect file dropped:

```
def detect_file(watch_folder_path):
    """ Detect a file dropped """
    watched_files = os.listdir(watch_folder_path)
    if len(watched_files) > 0:
        filename = watched_files[0]
        print "File located :, filename
```

Comment: What platform are you on?  What filesystem are you using?

Comment: I just noticed that someone has kindly written a portable Python library to do this: https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/  This used to be something platform-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a linux system I would suggest [inotifywatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) as it seems to be as it can be configure per events, like **create**, **move_to** and more.

There is a python wrapper [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) for it which which you can invoke like this:

```
python -m pyinotify -v /my-dir-to-watch
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
known_files = []

def detect_file(watch_folder_path):
    files = os.listdir(watch_folder_path)
    for file in files:
        if file not in known_files:                   
            #RAISE ALERT e.g. send email
            known_files.append(file)
```

Add the file to the `known_files` list once the alert has been raised so that it does not keep alerting.

You will then want to run `detect_files()` on repeat at a frequency of your discretion. I recommend using `Timer` to achieve this. Or even more simply, execute this function inside a `while True:` statement, and add in `time.sleep(60)` to run the `detect_files()` check every 60 seconds for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any dependency for your project you can rely on a script to compute the changes for your files. Assuming this script will always run you can write the following code:

```
def is_interesting_file(f):
    interesting_extensions = ['zip', 'json', 'xml', 'ini']
    file_extension = f.split('.')[-1]
    if file_extension in interesting_extension:
        return True
    return False

watch_folder_path = 0
previous_watched_files = set()

while True:
    watched_files = set(os.listdir(watch_folder_path))
    new_files = watched_files.difference(previous_watched_files)
    interesting_files = [filename for filename in new_files if is_interesting_file(filename)]
    #Do something with your interesting files
```

If you want to run this script on a cron or something like that using this approach, you can always save the directory listing in a file or simple database as sqlite and assign it to the `previous_watched_files` variable. Then you can make one iteration watching the directory for changes, clear the db/file records and creating them again with the updated listing results.